# Friend variable not passing to other forms

Tags: vb.net

I declared variable MemberID as Friend in the MainForm.
MemberID is the returned value of a query

```
MemberID = MembershipsTableAdapter.RetrieveMemberID(LoginUsernameTextBox.Text,
                                                    LoginPassTextBox.Text)
```

I get the correct values in MainForm
but when I try to use the value in another form using MainForm.MemberID, the value becomes zero

plz help

Comment: Please show your definition of MemberID.

Comment: Add `Sub New` to your MainForm class.  Set a breakpoint on it.  You'll probably discover that you create more than one instance of it.

Comment: Did you make `MemberID` `Public`?

Comment: I tried making it public and it worked. Thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

I think that if you declare it only public, it will lose it's value on the other form. Try declaring it `Public Shared`